# T-SQL: Dynamically change working view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, view

I have a stored procedure that works with a view `Customer_A` ***or*** a view `Customer_B` according to a parameter. The parameter changes the view but not the underlying query.

I don't want to write two different stored procedure to just change the working view.

Is it possible to have something like a local synonym to the view to just change the pointed view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use sp_executesql and QuoteName.
QuoteName will put brackets around the name you pass and sp_executesql will execute a dynamically created SQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RunView
    @ViewName VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = 
    N'SELECT * FROM ' + QuoteName(@ViewName) 

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is to add a new view:

```
CREATE VIEW Customers
AS
   SELECT *, --TODO, Name columns
          'A' as CustomerName
   FROM Customer_A
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *, --Ditto
          'B'
   FROM Customer_B
```

And now your stored procedure can query it and select the appropriate data based on the `CustomerName` column. Of course, you only need this new view because you've made the mistake of embedding actual data that you want to query over (such as the customers name) inside of *metadata* instead (a view's *name*).

(It may also be that the views `Customer_A` and `Customer_B` should be implemented atop a single generic view that already contains the union of all customer data, and my view above is just recreating that underlying query)

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic SQL for that

```
declare @tablename
select @tablename = 'customerA'
exec('select * from ' + @tablename)
```

Comment: This is prone to SQL injection isn't it? I had a lot of whooping in the past for such kind of answers...:)

Comment: Only if the user input can be part of the query. Otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

```
create view Customer_A as select 1 a
GO

create view Customer_B as select 2 a
GO

create procedure p_test
(
@view int
) with recompile
as
if @view = 1 
 select * from Customer_A
else if @view = 2
 select * from Customer_B

GO

exec p_test 1
exec p_test 2
```